# Universal autocorrect for Mac

Tags: macos, text, autocorrect

I'd been using a spelling auto-correct in Windows that worked amazingly well (without being annoying). It basically uses the list of most commonly typos from Wikipedia and substitutes any occurrence from it, if the user types that, with the correct spelling.

http://www.biancolo.com/articles/autocorrect/

It uses the software Autohotkey to do this.

Is there any way something similar can be done on the Mac? (Karabiner is a software that does some of the things AutoHotkey does, but from what I know I wouldn't be able to do this.)

Comment: Is your question more specifically about third-party auto-correct integration?

Comment: My question is about a way to implement autocorrect in the way I have described of the  on the Mac.

Comment: Ok, someone misunderstood your question, I believe, when they answered. Because OS X has autocorrect built in it, but nothing super obvious as far as compatibility with 3rd-party autocorrect extensions.

Comment: The autocorrect built into OS X is pretty lousy in comparison–it misses most of the common typos and at times incorrectly "corrects" words. The autocorrect program I am talking was many orders of magnitude better–I speak from a long experience of using both. Hence my question specifically specifically being if there's any "text replacement" programs for Mac (free or paid) that could do something similar.

Comment: Have you looked at Typeitforme?

Comment: No, but I have aText (another text expander) installed already. But unlike AuthoHotkey there seems to be no way to specify text substitutions to done based on a text file... which is the specific functionality I am looking for ultimately. I will look at Typeitforme but I doubt it has that feature.